# Multiple where in (select) slow

Tags: mysql, performance, where-clause

I'm creating a procedure that searches for result in a database with about 700k rows.

It looks like this (somewhat simplified):

```
BEGIN
    SET `page` = `page`*8;
    SELECT 
        businessName

        FROM tbl_business as bs

        INNER JOIN tbl_categories as ct
            ON ct.catId = bs.catId

        WHERE 
            (
             MATCH(businessName, businessShortDescription) AGAINST (`q`) 
             OR 
             businessName like CONCAT(`q`, '%')
            )

            AND
            (
             bs.catId IN (SELECT * FROM tmp_search_child_cats) 
             OR 
             ct.catPId IN (SELECT * FROM tmp_search_parent_cats)
            )

        ORDER BY score DESC

        LIMIT `page`, 8;
END
```

catPId is parent ID, which menas that a category can have a parent. Terrible solution, but I'm working with an old db.

I need this to run lightning fast (in a couple of milliseconds).

The temporary tables have only one column with category ID's, like so:

```
|-- cat --|
|    5    |
|   234   |
|    9    |
|---------|
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How fast is it running now? Can you include some sample data to test with?

Comment: Right now it uses ~2-3 seconds.

How should I include sample data?
I can't exactly post 700 000 rows of data...

Comment: If you were able to post 5-10 rows of sample data and expected results it would be helpful. That way, other users can recreate it using [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to make sure their new query produces the same results as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might not be perfect, but what I ended up doing was to actually join the input into a string, and add that to the WHERE IN().

e.g. WHERE IN (3,4,5) etc.

However, if one does go for this approach, be very mindful of SQL injection.